# Change icon of application on runtime

Tags: delphi

I have an EXE (App1.exe) file with a specific icon, and another EXE (App2.exe) file with another specific icon.

The App2 is embedded as a resource in the App1 project, but I want to stop using this resource, and leave the entire work in App1.exe only.
But, after executing the App1.exe, I want to save it in another file (copy it to another file), with the icon of App2.exe... I have the .ico file for App2.exe, this is not the problem. But how to have App1.exe with original icon, and another App1.exe with the icon of App2.exe when I copy it to another file, is that possible with simple code?

Comment: Use [`UpdateResource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049.aspx) to replace the icon resource of the copied file.

Comment: Copying exe files around is a bad idea for many reasons. Use command line args to specify behaviour and choose icons depending on those args.

Comment: Or, instead of command line args, have your app1.exe contain both icons. Use a mechanism like mutexes to have app1 check if another instance is already running, then change to the second icon.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the problem is that my file, will substitute the original Adobe PDF Reader, so, I need the exe to have the icon from Adobe, to not mess things up... It's not only while running, I need the file itself, to have that icon. While the first exe, have no sense to stay with this icon.

Comment: Your file using the Adobe PDF Reader icon is not only a violation of Adobe's copyright, it's malware-like for the user of your software (masquerading as legitimate software when it is not). People here should not be assisting you in creating malware.

Comment: I agree with Ken; this sounds like a loader for Acrobat to bypass activation verification. (Acrobat Reader doesn't need one since it's free)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if i understand what you want exactlly 
I think you should copy it then change icon
this code will update exe icon from another exe file

```
unit iconchanger;


interface

uses windows;

  type
    PICONDIRENTRYCOMMON = ^ICONDIRENTRYCOMMON;
    ICONDIRENTRYCOMMON = packed record
    bWidth             : Byte;  // Width, in pixels, of the image
    bHeight            : Byte;  // Height, in pixels, of the image
    bColorCount        : Byte;  // Number of colors in image (0 if >=8bpp)
    bReserved          : Byte;  // Reserved ( must be 0)
    wPlanes            : Word;  // Color Planes
    wBitCount          : Word;  // Bits per pixel
    dwBytesInRes       : DWord; // How many bytes in this resource?
    end;

    PICONDIRENTRY      = ^ICONDIRENTRY;
    ICONDIRENTRY       = packed record
    common             : ICONDIRENTRYCOMMON;
    dwImageOffset      : DWord; // Where in the file is this image?
    end;

    PICONDIR           = ^ICONDIR;
    ICONDIR            = packed record
    idReserved         : Word; // Reserved (must be 0)
    idType             : Word; // Resource Type (1 for icons)
    idCount            : Word; // How many images?
    idEntries          : ICONDIRENTRY; // An entry for each image (idCount of 'em)
    end;

    PGRPICONDIRENTRY   = ^GRPICONDIRENTRY;
    GRPICONDIRENTRY    = packed record
    common             : ICONDIRENTRYCOMMON;
    nID                : Word;  // the ID
    end;

    PGRPICONDIR        = ^GRPICONDIR;
    GRPICONDIR         = packed record
    idReserved         : Word; // Reserved (must be 0)
    idType             : Word; // Resource type (1 for icons)
    idCount            : Word; // How many images?
    idEntries          : GRPICONDIRENTRY;  // The entries for each image
    end;

function UpdateApplicationIcon(srcicon : PChar; destexe : PChar) : Boolean;

implementation

function UpdateApplicationIcon(srcicon : PChar; destexe : PChar) : Boolean;
var hFile  : Integer;
    id     : ICONDIR;
    pid    : PICONDIR;
    pgid   : PGRPICONDIR;
    uRead  : DWord;
    nSize  : DWord;
    pvFile : PByte;
    hInst  : LongInt;
begin
result := False;
hFile := CreateFile(srcicon, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
if hFile > 0 then
   begin
   ReadFile(hFile, id, sizeof(id), uRead, nil);
   SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
   GetMem(pid, sizeof(ICONDIR) + sizeof(ICONDIRENTRY));
   GetMem(pgid, sizeof(GRPICONDIR) + sizeof(GRPICONDIRENTRY));

   ReadFile(hFile, pid^, sizeof(ICONDIR) + sizeof(ICONDIRENTRY), uRead, nil);
   move(pid^, pgid^, sizeof(GRPICONDIR));

   pgid^.idEntries.common := pid^.idEntries.common;
   pgid^.idEntries.nID := 1;
   nSize := pid^.idEntries.common.dwBytesInRes;

   GetMem(pvFile, nSize);
   SetFilePointer(hFile, pid^.idEntries.dwImageOffset, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
   ReadFile(hFile, pvFile^, nSize, uRead, nil);
   CloseHandle(hFile);

   hInst:=BeginUpdateResource(destexe, False);
   if hInst > 0 then
      begin
      UpdateResource(hInst, RT_ICON, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), LANG_NEUTRAL, pvFile, nSize);
      EndUpdateResource(hInst, False);
      result := True;
      end;

   FreeMem(pvFile);
   FreeMem(pgid);
   FreeMem(pid);
   end;
end;

end.
```

Save above unit with name `iconchanger` and add it to your project Call it like this after copying your file

```
procedure TForm1.BtnChangeIconClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    iconchanger.UpdateApplicationIcon(PChar(SourceFileName), PChar(DestinationFileName));
end;
```

`DestinationFileName` will now have `SourceFileName` Icon

Comment: Doesn't work on Delphi 10.3 + Windows 8. Even tried to clear icon cache.